# Binary Hash (not String) with MessageDigest

Tags: java, hash

```
byte[] input = {0xA,0xB,0xC,0xD};
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] digest = md.digest(input);
for(int i=0; i<digest.length; i++) {
    System.out.format("%x",digest[i]&0xff);
}
```

I know how to get the hash with a text string, but I don't get the correct digest for this input. The correct is:
SHA256(0xABCD) = 123d4c7ef2d1600a1b3a0f6addc60a10f05a3495c9409f2ecbf4cc095d000a6b

Comment: try: `byte[] input = {0xAB,0xCD};`

Comment: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

Comment: @M Ice Cast array elements to `byte` - it was only meant as a hint. `0x0A0B0C0D` is not the same as `0xABCD`.

Comment: @janez-kuhar ok, I got it. (byte)0xAB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] input = {(byte)0xAB,(byte)0xCD};
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] digest = md.digest(input);
for (int i=0; i < digest.length; i++) {
 sb.append(Integer.toString((digest[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```